# Parse CSV file into columns using PHP

Tags: php, csv, parsing

I'm unsure as to how I would add columns to  information I have within my CSV file. The three columns that I would like to have are Mobile Number, Carrier Name and Validity Status.

index.php:

```
<?php

if (($open = fopen("Book1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
{

while (($data = fgetcsv($open, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{       
$array[] = $data;
}

fclose($open);
}
echo "<pre>";
//To display array data
var_dump($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

My information currently displays as shown in the following code:

```
array(6) { [0]=> array(3) {
                [0]=> string(11) "0744395****"
                [1]=> string(9) " Vodafone"
                [2]=> string(6) " Valid"
            }
            [1]=>    array(3) {
                [0]=> string(11) "0744395****"
                [1]=> string(3) " EE"
                [2]=> string(6) " Valid"
            }
            [2]=> array(3) {
                [0]=> string(11) "0744395****"
                [1]=> string(6) " Three"
                [2]=> string(6) " Valid"
            }
            [3]=> array(3) {
                [0]=> string(11) "0744395****"
                [1]=> string(9) " Vodafone"
                [2]=> string(6) " Valid"
            }
            [4]=> array(3) {
                [0]=> string(11) "0744395****"
                [1]=> string(13) " Tesco Mobile"
                [2]=> string(10) " Not Valid"
            }
            [5]=> array(3) {
                [0]=> string(11) "0744395****"
                [1]=> string(3) " EE"
                [2]=> string(6) " Valid"
            } 
}
```

I would like for the information to be columned as shown below (online example I found):

```
[REPTILE] => Array(
        [0] => stdClass Object(
                [animal] => crocodile
                [type] => REPTILE
                [number] => 4
            )
    )

[BIRD] => Array(
        [0] => stdClass Object(
                [animal] => duck
                [type] => BIRD
                [number] => 2
            )
    )

[MAMMAL] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object(
                [animal] => koala
                [type] => MAMMAL
                [number] => 4
            )
        [1] => stdClass Object(
                [animal] => lion
                [type] => MAMMAL
                [number] => 5
            )
    )

[FISH] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object(
                [animal] => áéíóú
                [type] => FISH
                [number] => 3
            )
    )
```

This is how my information is stored within the CSV file:

```
0744395****, Vodafone, Valid
0744395****, EE, Valid
0744395****, Three, Valid
0744395****, Vodafone, Valid
0744395****, Tesco Mobile, Not Valid
0744395****, EE, Valid
```

Comment: Great, but how are you going to decide on which are `reptiles` or `birds` or `fish` or .... And when did mobile phones get clasified that way anyway??? PHP like all other programming languages stops short of down right Magic OR am I  the one getting the wrong end of the stick here

Comment: Oh I get it, that was just a bad example. If you want us to understand your requirement, spend a little time showing the **"WHAT I WANT"** array using data from the **"WHAT I STARTED WITH"** array and maybe it will all make sense

Comment: The animal, type and number is the part I'm hoping to have a similar output for the Mobile Number, Carrier Name and Validity Status. I just used that online code as an example of how I would like my code to be structured.

Comment: My bad. Maybe wasn't written or explained as well as I hoped so.

Comment: Do you want to group records per mobile phone operator? As noted already by @Riggs, please edit the question to show the "WHAT I WANT" array using data from the "WHAT I STARTED WITH" array.

Comment: It isn't required but it wouldn't hurt for it to look more organised

Comment: Show us the code you used to get the CSV file read into the array please

Comment: Should be on post now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newArray = [];

if (($fh = fopen("Book1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($fh, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $o = new stdClass;
        
        $o->MobileNumber    = trim($data[0]);
        $o->Carrier         = trim($data[1]);
        $o->ValidityStatus  = trim($data[2]);
        $newArray[$o->Carrier][] = $o;
    }
}
```

Should produce an array of Carriers, each with an array of objects with phone number and statuses inside

Comment: This is basically what your "WHAT I WANT" example suggests, so what did you have in mind

Comment: The way in the online example has [animal] => koala
                [type] => MAMMAL
                [number] => 4 I need [Mobile Number] => 07738******
                [Carrier] => EE
                [Validity Status] => Valid. I need this to display in this structure for each data output

Comment: Yea, that you will get from this code, but all the EE numbers will be under an array called EE like your `FISH` etc

Comment: array(1) {
  ["0744395****"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
      ["carrier"]=>
      string(11) "0744395****"
      ["phone"]=>
      string(9) " Vodafone"
      ["status"]=>
      string(6) " Valid"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
      ["carrier"]=>
      string(11) "0744395****"
      ["phone"]=>
      string(3) " EE"
      ["status"]=>
      string(6) " Valid"
    }

Comment: Oh for heavans sake, Then move the parts around ALL I did was get the order of the fields on the csv wrong

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the part where it says the number of characters in the string (string (9))?

Comment: Thats how `var_dump()` does it. You could do a `var_export()` that would also make it easier for us to copy/paste into code for testing